# Google SMTP cyrillic Subject

Tags: php, encoding, smtp

I am using Google smtp in my project, and here's a poblem. I am sending html letters with cyrillic text. Body is okay, but subject displaying with broken encoding (`Ð ÑÐ ÂµÐ¡ÐÐ¡â Ð¡ÐÐ ÑÐ Â·Ð¡ÐÐ ÑÐ Â»Ð ÑÐ Ñ`). Which encoding must be used to set cyrillic subject for Google SMTP? I tried utf-8 and windows-1251.

```
iconv('windows-1251','utf-8',"Тест розсилки")
mb_convert_encoding('Тест розсилки','Windows-1251')
mb_convert_encoding('Тест розсилки','UTF-8')
```

mb_detect_encoding returns 'utf-8'

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set Charset in PHPMailer config.

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with �� symbols arriving in mail subject, but windows-1251 fixed the problem.